# What are Moxxi's Portraits for?

Tags: borderlands-2

Are there ant other uses for the Moxxi pictures you collect in Borderlands 2: Badass Crater... other than the Obsession acheivement and prehaps taking one to a nearby portaloo a knocking out a quick 5 knuckle shuffle?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing. They are there for the achievement. That's literally all they do. Nothing else to say about them.